# Find the time to send a refresh message such that the probability of success is 0.99

Tags: probability

> A computer reserves a path in a network for 10 minutes. To extend the reservation the computer must successfully send a  “refresh” message before the expiry time. However, messages are lost with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Suppose that it takes 10 seconds to send a refresh request and receive an acknowledgment. When should the computer start sending refresh messages in order to have a 99% chance of successfully extending the reservation time?

My attempt:

Let $Y$ be the random variable that indicates the seconds left before the deadline. So

$$
Y=600-t-10N
$$
where $t$ is the time adjustment in seconds and $N$ is the number of attempts before a success is made.

The given states that we should have
$$
\Pr [Y≥0]=\Pr [N≤\frac{600-t}{10}] = 0.99
$$
Since $N$ has a geometric distribution:

$$
\Pr [N≤k]=\sum ^{k} _{i=1} (0.5)^i
$$
Which simplifies to , and upon using the corresponding value for $k$:

$$
\Pr [N≤\frac{600-t}{10}]=1-\frac{1}{2^{60-t/10}}= 0.99
$$
Giving $t=533.56$ so the required time to refresh is $600-533.56=66.44$ seconds.

---

I am really uncomfortable with this answer and solution particularly to how I modeled $Y$, can someone please check my work? Thank you very much

Comment: I am not sure you can use the geometric distribution like that if your upper bound isn't an integer. I think you have to take the floor which in the end would give you a range for $t$ which intuitively makes more sense to me than a single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question.  If so, then this answer may be completely wrong.

$2^{-6} > \frac{1}{100} > 2^{-7}.$

Therefore, the computer needs to plan on sending $7$ messages, if needed.  Since each message takes $10$ seconds, the computer should start sending the messages $70$ seconds before the expiration time.

**Edit**
A case could be made that even if my understanding of the problem is correct, the answer is still wrong.  For example, suppose that the computer doesn't start sending the messages until $61$ seconds before expiration.  Then, if needed, the computer sends the $7$th message $1$ second before expiration.

Does this mean that if the $7$th message succeeds, that it will be timely?  My original answer assumed not.  However, I leave this issue open.

Comment: You are right! Your answer is quick and efficient than mine. In conjunction with @ManateePink 's comment, the value of $t$ should be rounded off/adjusted such that $k$ is an integer. Nevertheless, the value $70$ seconds before the deadline also corresponds with my answer being rounded off. Thank you